# Very simple question : normed space is subspace of its bidual

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $X^{**}$is its bidual.

I’m trying to show $X \subseteq X^{**}$.

Let $J:X \to X^{**} $ be canonical embedding. Since it is an isometry (I’ve shown that) it is invertible.

$x \in X$ then $J(x) \in X^{**}$ thus $J^{-1}(J(x))=x$. How can I say  $J^{-1}(J(x))  \in X^{**}$?

I think I’m writing unnecessary things. I couldn’t show $x \in X^{**}$. It is probably so easy but I’m stuck.

I’m sorry in advance if there is any mistake.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you might have misinterpreted what is meant by "subspace" here - it's not that $X$ is literally a subspace (or even a subset) of $X^{**}$, but rather that there is a natural isometry from $X$ to $X^{**}$ - and the image of $X$ under this is sort of like a copy of $X$ lying in $X^{**}$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Therefore I should show $J(X)$ is subspace of $X^{**}$ and X is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $X^{**}$ which is $J(X)$ right?

Answer (score 1):

$X \subseteq X^{\ast\ast}$ is misleading: It's rather $J[X] \subseteq X^{\ast\ast}$, which is isometrically isomorphic to $X$, via $J$, so $\|J(x)\|=\|x\|$ (in the respective norms on $X^{\ast\ast}$ and $X$).

So we can conceptually see $J(x)$ (i.e. all point evaluations) as a "copy" of $X$ inside $X^{\ast\ast}$.

So no need to mess with $J^{-1}(J(x))$, that's just $x$ by definition.